# Laptop only boots when no internal drive is connected

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, hp-pavilion, voltage

TLDR: Laptop will not even boot to the BIOS menu when an internal SSD or HDD is connected, there is no visible damage on the motherboard. When booting from a sometimes working and long time taking USB live Debian install, networking does not work properly.

Last friday my laptop of about 3 years old [(hp pavilion 14-bf180nd)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05795786#AbT0) randomly broke on me (after some travel by train, but no severe bumps). Normally I have a laptop HDD and an M.2 SSD connected internally, but the laptop will not get past the boot screen when these are inserted, so not even the BIOS is accessible. When the hard drives are removed I need to wait about 30 seconds before the screen becomes backlit, and then I can press escape and use the BIOS normally. HP includes a BIOS recovery program to check for disk error etc., but this is not accessible because it says it is corrupted.

Once I can get in the BIOS I can change the boot order to boot off a USB, this (mostly) works. Ubuntu sometimes crashes, but live Debian works everytime. When in the OS, WiFi networks are seen but I am not able to connect. Ethernet is unable to use DHCP, and when setting a static IP I am able to send a few packets but always 90%+ packet loss.

I have visually checked the motherboard for damage but I am unable to find any. I checked a few capacitors for voltage lines, and they seem stable but unsure since I don't have any schematics/pcb layout.

When trying to use a USB WiFi adapter (since USB seems to work), the driver is unable to initialize the card.

I am unsure what the root cause is of these issues, to me it seems like there is some voltage line that is unstable or something like that. What could be a reasonable explanation for these issues and is it fixable?

Replacing the motherboard is not worth it seeing the age of the device, and cost.

I have knowledge of software and electronics but not so much of laptop/pc hardware. The battery in this laptop has been bad for over a year.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say it, but it sounds like the motherboard is bad, or at least mostly on it's way out.

The only thing you could possible try is to flash an updated BIOS onto the motherboard and see if that resolves anything for you.

Comment: I didn't specify in the original post but I flashed the latest BIOS version, but to no avail. TBH I would be satisfied with working networking, so I can use it as a server or desktop pc